# Java Scanner Not Blocking During Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, iteration, java.util.scanner

I am running into a problem where Scanner isn't blocking for user input during an indefinite while loop. I've tried using `hasNextLine()` and that hasn't worked. It just runs the loop infinitely calling `displayMenu()`.

```
     do {

        displayMenu();

        int response;
        while (iStream.hasNextLine()) {
            response = Integer.parseInt(iStream.nextLine());

            switch (response) {
                case 1:
                    decodeMessage(getPhrase());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    encodeMessage(getPhrase());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    displayAlphabet();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                    break;
                default:
                    done = false;
            }
        }

    }
    while (!done);
```

I've also tried not using `hasNextLine()` but I end up with a `NoSuchElementException` as it runs through perfectly the first time but on the second iteration, it doesn't block for user input.

```
    do {

        displayMenu();

        int response = Integer.parseInt(iStream.nextLine());

            switch (response) {
                case 1:
                    decodeMessage(getPhrase());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    encodeMessage(getPhrase());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    displayAlphabet();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                    break;
                default:
                    done = false;

        }

    }
    while (!done);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why the nested while loops? Why not just use one while loop that checks for done with an if block that checks `hasNextLine()`?

Comment: I just don't understand why it isn't blocking. For `System.in` it should be, right? If I change it to be conditional, would I throw the switch body in the if statement? I would still infinitely call `displayMenu()` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
private static void displayMenu ()
{
    System.out.println ("Menu:");
    System.out.println ("\t1: Decode message");
    System.out.println ("\t2: Encode message");
    System.out.println ("\t3: Display alphabet");
    System.out.println ("\t4: Exit");
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        displayMenu();

        switch (Integer.parseInt (scanner.nextLine ()))
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println ("Decoding...");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println ("Encoding...");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println ("Displaying alphabet...");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Exitting...");
                done = true;
                break;
            default:
                done = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I was declaring and closing new scanner objects in the `getPhrase()` method. Passing the previously declared object instead fixed it.